# JSON giving undefined error when fetching using variable but working when using hardcoded index

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to load some JSON data from a JSON file and carrying out some data manipulation on it for an app I'm trying to build. However, when looping through the data, I'm getting an undefined error which makes it seem that property is missing from the JSON object when I use a looping variable to access the objects. However, when I index the JSON array with a hardcoded number, the property loads fine. I am wondering if someone can help me out with this. I've attached an example of the code and the JSON to this.

I have tried stringifying the JSON and parsing it again and tried both accessing the JSON using square brackets as well as the full stop and they all lead to the same result.

Code to access:

```
import ontology from '../../data/ontology.json'

const totalAnswerList = ontology.answers

for (var i = 0; i <= totalAnswerList.length; i++) {
            var wordID = totalAnswerList[i] // wordID.id returns undefined
            var wordID2 = totalAnswerList[0] // wordID2.id works
            alert(JSON.stringify(wordID) + JSON.stringify(wordID2) + '\nWord ID hardcoded: ' + wordID2.id)
}
```

```
//ontology.json
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "id": "examination",
            "category_id": "examination",
            "synonyms": ["examination"]
        }, ...
    ], ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided works as expected, but the issue is the *last* element is `undefined` because of your for loop constraints. You likely want `i < totalAnswerList.length` and not `<=`. Because if the array is 5 elements long, you want to loop through `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4` (and not `5`, which will be `undefined`).

```
import ontology from "./ontology.json";

const totalAnswerList = ontology.answers;

for (var i = 0; i < totalAnswerList.length; i++) {
  // ...
}
```